# Read input configuration json file from scala

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spark-submit, argo-workflows

I have Argo shared workflow for spark submit in Dataproc cluster GCP.
I have some input parameters for the workshow as shown below.

- cluster
- project
- properties and so on

In My work flow Under the **properties** input section, I have pass the values
as shown below

```
 arguments:
   parameters:
     - name : project
       value : "testProj"

     - name : cluster
       value : "testcluster"


     - name : properties
       value : "--properties=spark.submit.deploymode=client,spark-extraJavaOptions=-Dargument1 -Dconfig.file="input_config.json"
```

The **input_config.json** file is not in the project location and it is outside of the project location.

I am unable to read the **input_config.json** through properties as shown above.

How to read **"input_config.json"** present in kubernetes project  or gcs bucket path in my properties config.?